# Can Special Combo Takedown be used on any enemy?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In Batman: Arkham City you can execute a variety of special combat moves once your combo meter is up (e.g. that multiple batarang move, the super bat stun thing, etc.). One of these moves is the Special Combo takedown which is supposed to be "an unblockable takedown that will instantly K.O. an enemy."

Now I've used this move many a time on normal thug enemies, but I am wondering if it also works on the bigger guys, such as lieutenants and titans?

It's pretty hard to attempt this myself as there are usually many other normal thug enemies that my character will default to using the attack on first, and I don't want to lose my combo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, special combo takedown cannot be used on every enemy. Invalid targets are lieutenants, titans, and Joker (who takes the hit but keeps on trucking, IIRC). Valid targets are thugs (including armed and armored) and ninja.

Comment: Perfect answer.